# NSLayoutConstraint and determining which subview is wider

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I create a `UISwitch` and a `UILabel` in a subclassed container `UIView`:

```
UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [UISwitch new];
toggleSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
[toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggleDetected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.toggleSwitch = toggleSwitch;

[self addSubview:toggleSwitch];

UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:HELVETICA_FONT_STYLE_BOLD size:10.0];
label.text = [self.text uppercaseString];

self.label = label;

[self addSubview:label];

[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[toggleSwitch]-5-[label]" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toggleSwitch, label)]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[toggleSwitch]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toggleSwitch, label)]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1 constant:0]];
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

which gives me this:

[image]

The last two constraints lets me give the container view an "intrinsic size". The container would be rect(0,0,0,0). I then tell the right side should be the same width as the `UILabel` and the bottom should be the same value as the `UILabel` to give a height.

The problem I may run is when the label is shorter then the switch:

[image]

This will lead to an issue with the switch container view not being placed correct:

```
[contentImageView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[toggleView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(toggleView)]];
```

[image]

So I would like to base the constraints on the longer of the two, either the switch or the label but I'm not sure how to determine which is wider. The switch is a constant width, but I can not get the width of the label until after is added to screen which would be too late.

I've tried adding `[self layoutIfNeeded]` and `[label layoutIfNeeded]`:

```
[self layoutIfNeeded];
[label layoutIfNeeded];

DLog(@"label: %@", label);
DLog(@"switch: %@", toggleSwitch);

//Constraints added here
```

result:

```
DEBUG | -[SwitchContainerView createContainerSwitch] | label: <UILabel: 0x7af7c6d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'ON'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7af7c7b0>>
DEBUG | -[SwitchContainerView createContainerSwitch] | switch: <UISwitch: 0x7af7b370; frame = (0 0; 51 31); layer = <CALayer: 0x7af7b430>>
```

Any suggestions on determining which of the two is wider?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for *you* to "determine which is wider" - just set up the constraints and walk away, and let auto layout do its job. Simply use two constraints with inequalities / priorities to determine the width of the containing superview relative to the two subviews.

I achieved this arrangement using constraints alone - all I'm doing at this point is changing the text of the label:

[image]

[image]

Whenever the label text is short, the superview is 20 points wider than the switch. Whenever the label text is long, the superview is 20 points wider than the label. That is configured *entirely with constraints*. Here are the constraints that determine the width of the yellow superview in my screen shots (as shown in the debugger console):

```
UIView:0x7fdb03435450.width >= UISwitch:0x7fdb034355c0.width + 20 priority:999
UIView:0x7fdb03435450.width >= UILabel:0x7fdb03433260'Infundibulum'.width + 20 priority:999
```

The constraints do not change; I set them up once and the layout just works, and keeps working as the text of the label changes.

Comment: I used the term intrinsic size because its size will be determined by the size of its sub views. If I did not use the `NSLayoutAttributeRight` and `NSLayoutAttributeBottom`, the view would have no size unless I set the height and width which is what I was trying to avoid. I appreciate your response and stating it is possible in Interface Building. Unfortunately I do not like using it and prefer to do it code.

Comment: Fine, you can do it in code. That has nothing to do with what I'm saying. You would simply make all the same constraints I made. I made them in IB, you would make them in code. No problem. I'm just showing that a pure constraints solution works. No "if", no for you to need to know which is wider, no need for constraints that come and go. Just make all the constraints and walk away. What I'm saying is that you do _not_ "determine which is wider" - let the constraints do all the work.

Comment: I did try solving it with inequalities/priorities but I am unsure how to set the values. I could set the min width of say 55 with a high priority and then a second constraint based on label width with a lower priority, but wouldn't that always default to the min width of 55? If I do the reverse, wouldn't I run into the issue of the container view being less then the min width of 55 if the label is only 20 width?

Comment: I explained in my answer. Width of the superview is based on two greater-than-or-equal constraints - one against the label width, one against the switch width.

Comment: I've posted the actual width constraints as part of my answer.