# How to align two UILabels with dynamic heights to the bottom of a UICollectionViewCell using autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell that has two labels in it - side by side. They are supposed to take up equal width and the height of the tallest should align to the bottom and push out the container so that it stretches to the tallest of the two. What kind of autolayout constraints can I put on these labels to get that behavior without manual intervention? Is that even possible to define using autolayout constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use auto layout constraints to size a container view based on the tallest of its contents. That part is easy.

([Here, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831713/341994), I'm sizing a container based on which of two things inside it is wider. It's exactly the same problem, in effect.)

The problem here, though, is that UICollectionViewCells are not self-sizing, so it's hard to see what auto layout has to do with anything. You're going to have to size the cell in code no matter what.